# How to modifying the behaviour of the Python logging facility?

Tags: python, logging

I would like to change the way in which messages with DEBUG and INFO level are displayed when using Python's native logging facility. By "change", I do not mean altering the format but adding an extra logical level. For example:

```
# This is a global variable that is set at the time of initializing the logging.
required_verbosity_level = 7

# This variable is passed with each call to the logger.
supplied_verbosity_level = 5
```

So when creating the logger we pass the global requirement.

```
logger = LoggerBridge(required_verbosity_level = 7)
```

Then when we call the method, we pass the appropriate level:

```
logger.debug('This is a debug message.', supplied_verbosity_level = 5)
```

So internally, the logic would be (5<7) and this will make the message **visible** due to the fact that the `supplied` value meets the `required` one. However, in the following case:

```
logger.debug('This is a debug message.', supplied_verbosity_level = 11)
```

The message **will never be visible** as the `supplied` value is higher than the `required` value. The question is: Where would be the best place to implement such a behaviour?

Right now, I tried couple of things based on inheriting the current Logger class and overriding the internal behaviour, something known as the `mixin` approach:

```
class LoggerBridge(object):
    def __init__(self, required_verbosity_level):
        self.required_verbosity_level = required_verbosity_level

    def _log_bridge(self, logger):
        logger(message)

    def info(self, message, supplied_verbosity_level):
        if supplied_verbosity_level < self.required_verbosity_level:
            self._log_bridge(logging.info, message)

    def debug(self, message, supplied_verbosity_level):
        if supplied_verbosity_level < self.required_verbosity_level:
            self._log_bridge(logging.debug, message)
```

In theory, this seems to be working. However, is that the right way? Is there a way to solve this by using any of the built-in logging bits, such as a `custom handler` or a `custom filter`?

Answer (score 1):

If all you want is custom debug levels then it's supported *out of the box*.
You set custom debug level (`required_verbosity_level` in your example) on logger using [setLevel()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.setLevel) and then you use [log()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.log) method for logging and pass your custom level (`supplied_verbosity_level` in your example).
If you want to further customize this logic you might want to override [isEnabledFor()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.isEnabledFor) method.

Comment: I am a bit reluctant to mess around with the levels. As that would require to define the levels explicitly and things can get out of hand in terms of compatibility etc. Maybe I can utilise `logging.disable` somehow?

Comment: @symbolix What do you mean by *that would require to define the levels explicitly*? Levels can be arbitrary integers and you don't need to define any levels up front. `info(...)` is the same as calling `log(20,...)` and you can call `log(<arbitrary_integer>, ...)` too. Binding a level name with some integer by using `addLevelName()` is optional. `logging.disable()` is a module-level function and it acts upon all loggers whereas in your example you set level for one, specific logger. Also I think you have the levels in your example backwards, higher level should mean greater importance.

Comment: Thanks, I will consider this solution. I guess, for the purpose of learning, I might go after a solution that set this up as a Logger class.